# update-alternatives appears to have killed php-fpm

Tags: php-fpm

I'm running php7.4-fpm on a Raspberry Pi as a server (equivalent to a fully updated Debian 11.8; Apache 2.4 web server). It's been running smoothly for many months. Last night, something stopped the php-fpm master process. I was able to restart it once I was aware of the problem.

syslog shows

```
Dec 27 04:21:33 cameo4b systemd[1]: php7.4-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=7/BUS
Dec 27 04:21:33 cameo4b systemd[1]: php7.4-fpm.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Dec 27 04:21:33 cameo4b systemd[1]: php7.4-fpm.service: Consumed 4h 34min 43.800s CPU time.
```

At the same time, alternatives.log shows

```
update-alternatives 2023-12-27 04:21:33: run with --quiet --remove php-fpm.sock /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock
update-alternatives 2023-12-27 04:21:33: link group php-fpm.sock fully removed
```

That is what appears to have killed the php-fpm master process. When I restarted a few hours later (with systemctl restart) alternatives.log shows:

```
update-alternatives 2023-12-27 08:30:13: run with --quiet --install /run/php/php-fpm.sock php-fpm.sock /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock 74
update-alternatives 2023-12-27 08:30:13: link group php-fpm.sock updated to point to /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock
```

I cannot find what is running update-alternatives. There doesn't seem to be a routine cron job which references it. (The most likely candidate is `apt-compat`, but that seems to run at 06:47; apt logs show only a manual security upgrade from a few days ago as I'd expect).

Why would update-alternatives run automatically? What ran it? And why in such a way that it leaves php-fpm not running? The Alternatives system does indeed manage the location of the default socket.

```
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/php-fpm.sock 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Dec 27 08:30 /etc/alternatives/php-fpm.sock -> /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock
```